# LabVIEW: how to control two events one after the other from one button

Tags: events, labview

I am working on a project where I have to send arguments by a command line to a python file (using system exec) and then visualize the results saved in a folder after the python file finishes executing. I need to have this by only clicking on one button, so my question is, if there is any way to realize this scenario or maybe if I can order the events.
[image]

Now I have included the flat sequence structure to the block Diagram so I can order the events, but I had an issue with making the program (the python file) running every time I press the Test button (it only runs in the first time I click on the Test button), I tried to use the while loop but I couldn't execute it again unless I restart the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you phrased your question makes me think that you want to wait until the command you call via system exec finished and then run some code. You could simply use a sequence structure for this.

However, if you need to do this *asynchronously*, i.e. launch the command and get an event when the command finished so you can draw the results, you will need to resort to asynchronous techniques like "Start Asynchronous Call" and "Wait On Asynchronous Call", or for example queues and a separate code area for the background-work.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually I used the flat sequence structure and it worked the way I wanted to ! but I have another problem when I use a while loop in the first frame (so the  python program will be executed everytime I press the button ), it won't execute the second frame (where reading from images file should be done).. I have tried to change the mechanical action of the button to switch to have True and False cases but nothing has changed.. either the program is excuted once with reading from file or it could be executed many times but without  reading from file..

Comment: I can share the Vi or a screen capture if it's needed

Comment: @Asky this sounds like an extension of this question, so please update this question with the information in your comment and add the VI diagram as a [VI Snippet](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x2PkCAI&l=en-GB).

Comment: It really does sound like an extension of the question. Anyhow, you should not have the While-Loop querying the Button inside the left frame of the Sequence structure, but have the entire sequence structure inside the while-loop, so that everytime the button is pressed, the sequence structure executes (and runs your python script and the [Read file and visualize data] part).

Comment: I have indeed edited the Post with the new block diagram, I have made many changements with the while loop but nothing has worked correctly, still the "system Exec" runs only once. The second frame is for reading the file of images.

Comment: You need to put the event structure inside the while loop, not the other way around. If you plan to create a bigger program around this, you might want to check out the examples that LabVIEW ships with (Help -> Find Examples).

Comment: @PhilMasteG unfortunately, it didn't work.. I guess the problem resides in the while loop in the second frame, when I use the vision acquistion instead of the  while loop it works, but in this case I'm obliged to read one image instead of all the images in the file.

Comment: I would rather avoid using "Flat Sequence Structure". Almost always better solution is to use the error wire to determine process flow and use subVIs to encapsulate low level code.

Answer (score 1):

Use "wait until completion?" input of System Exec function to make sure the script finished execution, then proceed with the results visualization part.

Comment: That's actually the default if unwired, so my guess is the question was more about the "how do I 'then proceed' "-part, but yes, that input must not be wired to a false constant, of course.

Comment: and what's exactly problematic? could you please post your code?

Comment: @MateuszOwczarek Thank you for your reply ! actually I forgot that I wired the " wait until completion" to false so I unwired it and used PhilMasteG solution to get the result I looked for.